# SDcard /dev/sdb2 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here

Tags: linux, partitioning, sd-card, software-raid, hardware-raid

I divided my sdcard into 2 partitions, but It got an error and couldn't create a new partition.

> Error:
>    /dev/sdb2 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!

My /dev/sdb was not mounted, and the output of command lsblk was:

> cxphong@cxphong:~/Desktop$ lsblk
>
> NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
>   sr0            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
>   sda             8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
>   ├─sda1          8:1    0 118.8G  0 part 
>   ├─sda2          8:2    0 147.7G  0 part /media/DATA 
>   ├─sda3          8:3    0 137.1G  0 part 
>   ├─sda4          8:4    0     1K  0 part 
>   ├─sda5          8:5    0  1023M  0 part [SWAP]
>   └─sda6          8:6    0  61.2G  0 part /
>   sdb             8:16   1   3.7G  0 disk 
>   ├─sdb1          8:17   1  70.6M  0 part 
>   ├─sdb2          8:18   1   3.6G  0 part 
>   ├─sdb1 (dm-0) 252:0    0  70.6M  0 part 
>   └─sdb2 (dm-1) 252:1    0   3.6G  0 part

I couldn't delete /dev/sdb1 (dm-0) & /dev/sdb2 (dm-1). What are they?

**Edit:**
Hi, I solved it by removing /dev/dm-0 & /dev/dm-1 
**sudo dmsetup remove /dev/dm-0** 
**sudo dmsetup remove /dev/dm-1**

Reject & Inject Sdcard again, then It gone!

Comment: I solved it: sudo dmsetup remove /dev/dm-0, sudo dmsetup remove /dev/dm-1

Comment: I think it would be useful if you posted your own answer.